# csvwriter doesn't write data into csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a list of tuple which named output and I want to write it in csv file.
I've tried this.

```
f = open('filename.csv' ,'w')
w = csv.writer(f)
w.writerow(output)
f.close()
```

There's no error message. It just don't work.

Comment: What directory is it writing to is what you should be asking.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote works for me, as long as your `output` variable is an iterable object, such as a `list`. For example:

```
import csv

output = ["Foo", "Bar"]

f = open("filename.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(f)
w.writerow(output)
f.close()
```

Successfully created the file: "filename.csv", with contents:

```
Foo,Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tried everything, also make sure that you antivirus allows your IDE create files. Try disabling your antivirus or white-listing your IDE in your antivirus.